# List files in zip subdirectory

Tags: excel, linux, zip, unzip

To list all the files in a spreadsheet (xlsx) file, I can do:

```
$ unzip -l /Users/david/Desktop/myspreadsheet.xlsx
      698  01-01-1980 00:00   xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
1415625191  01-01-1980 00:00   xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
     6798  01-01-1980 00:00   xl/theme/theme1.xml
     2315  01-01-1980 00:00   xl/styles.xml
   779218  01-01-1980 00:00   xl/sharedStrings.xml
      322  01-01-1980 00:00   xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels
     9840  01-01-1980 00:00   xl/printerSettings/printerSettings1.bin
      640  01-01-1980 00:00   docProps/core.xml
      797  01-01-1980 00:00   docProps/app.xml
```

From here we can see that the spreadsheet has one sheet -- `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`. Is there a way to only see the zip contents of the `xl/worksheets/` folder? For example, doing something like:

```
$ unzip -l /Users/david/Desktop/myspreadsheet.xlsx xl/worksheets
```

The most I could find from **man** was:

> ```
>    -l     list archive files (short format).  The names, uncompressed file sizes and modification dates  and
>           times of the specified files are printed, along with totals for all files specified.  If UnZip was
>           compiled with OS2_EAS defined, the -l option also lists columns  for  the  sizes  of  stored  OS/2
>           extended  attributes (EAs) and OS/2 access control lists (ACLs).  In addition, the zipfile comment
>           and individual file comments (if any) are displayed.  If a file was archived  from  a  single-case
>           file  system  (for example, the old MS-DOS FAT file system) and the -L option was given, the file-
>           name is converted to lowercase and is prefixed with a caret (^).
> ```

But it seems like there are tons of other options. Is there a way to do the above?

Comment: `unzip -l spreadsheet.xlsx "xl/worksheets/*"` maybe?

Comment: @Shawn yes that works: `unzip -l spreadsheet.xlsx "xl/worksheets/*.xml"`. How did you figure that one out? Also want to post that into an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: I read the Arguments section of the man page...

Comment: @Shawn got it -- which section shows that?

Comment: The Arguments section?